What can be done to help LLMs consume a multi-lingual website?
Since ChatGPT is a bit more real-time than it used to be, I often find myself using that instead of Google to research products/services/platforms. That got me wondering whether there is anything that website owners can be doing to optimize for LLMs.
I quickly found the llms.txt standard proposed by Jeremy Howard
https://llmstxt.org/#proposal
It seems to function a bit like a sitemap or robots.txt and I can see it becoming widely adopted.
Does anyone have practical advice for implementing this on a multilingual site?
Maybe it would be a good way to provide high quality translations of key information even if the bulk of the site is just machine translated.

You're language is rather indirect. Are you actually an owner of a multilingual website? What motivates you to provide your content in an optimal way to LLMs? Many website owners regard LLMs as a great threat to their bottom line.
